# Windows 7 turned mapped network drive into a local drive. How do I remove it?

Tags: windows-7, network-shares

Windows 7 Home Premium.

So, occasionally I have to connect to a Windows share for work from home, and I mapped this share to a Q drive (Convention at the company is to map this share to Q).

I'm not sure when this happened, but for some reason, now Windows [shows Q as a local drive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXaWj.gif):

and when I try to access it, I get ["Q:\ is not accessible"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWQrJ.gif)

How do I correct this?

Not sure if it's relevant, but I don't always have access to the network the share is on (it's accessed via VPN).  But it happens even when I have access to the share (when connected via VPN).

Answer (score 1):

Try this from a command prompt:

```
net use q: /delete
```

Comment: This did not work, unfortunately, I get:
`The network connection could not be found.

More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 2250.`

The help message is: `The network connection could not be found.`

Answer (score 1):

Some versions of MS Office install via a "Click-to-Run" process that creates a kind of virtual machine on your computer and puts it on a Q drive (which can interfere with your own use of Q for a mapped drive).
Sounds like you might have installed this thing.

I've got a page on my PPT FAQ site that explains more, and gives some suggestions for converting a CTR version of Office 2010 to a real, less annoying one.

Office 2010 Click-to-Run
http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ01094_Office_2010_Click-to-Run.htm

Comment: I don't have Office installed, but thanks for the suggestion!